# Javascript popup - Works in FF & Chrome, fails in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to figure out why the following simple popup will not work in IE9.  FF & Chrome popup as expected, but IE does not appear to do anything when the link is clicked.  I tried the IE9 debugger, but didn't get any helpful information out of it.

In the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function JSPopup(linkref) {
        window.open(linkref,"Report Definitions","width=600,height=480");
        return false;
    }
```

In the body:

```
<a href="#" onClick="JSPopup('./Web Report Definitions.html')"> <strong>Report Definitions</strong> </a>
```

Thanks for your help,

Filip

Comment: You're missing a comma and an opening double-quote mark after `"Report Definitions"`

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy paste error from posting. The comma and opening quote is in the code.

Comment: Does IE block this type of pop up?

Comment: Nope, it can do the popup - turned out to be a space issue with the name given to the popup in window.open

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was the name given to the popup - IE doesn't allow spaces, FF & Chrome do:

```
window.open(linkref,"Report Definitions","width=600,height=480");
```

needed to be changed to:

```
window.open(linkref,"ReportDefinitions","width=600,height=480");
```

This works across browsers.

Filip

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the security changes made in IE6. Now you can only call "window.open" from within a user-initiated event. For example, your code would work inside an element's onclick event. The "window.open" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx MSDN page says this:

> "This method must use a user-initiated action, such as clicking on a link or tabbing to a link and pressing enter, to open a pop-up window. The Pop-up Blocker feature in Internet Explorer 6 blocks windows that are opened without being initiated by the user."

Example...

```
function popUpWin(url,wtitle,wprop){
   if (!window.open){ return; } // checking if we can't do this basic function

   // Kill if(win), since win was a local var this was a usless check
   var win = window.open(url,wtitle,wprop);

   // next line important in case you open multiple with the same 'wtitle' 
   // to make sure the window is reused and refocused.
   if (win && win.focus){ win.focus(); }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case here, given that the JS is called after the onclick on the html link.  The user is clicking this link, so the above doesn't appear apply since it is a user initiated action.